# why does not my AS3 code work ? Why variable does not constantly increasing, but equal 1?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

At first? I am newbie in actionscript 3 and Flashdevelop.
Why value var a does not constantly increasing, but just equal 1? Where i have mistakes?

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Main() {
           var a: int;
            a = a + 1;
            trace(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that both answers from Vesper and moosefetcher below are correct. Your constructor function `Main()` only gets executed once. And if you were to (somehow) call it again, the variable `a` is only a local variable and would be reset each time you called the function (promote it to a member variable instead).

Answer (score 3):

The Main function is the constructor function of your Main Class, so gets called only once. Variable 'a' therefore gets incremented only once. You will need to add a loop of some kind to have 'a' incremented more often.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is local to the function, so each time the function is called, a new variable with default value (for `int` type it's 0) is created, then incremented, then traces, resulting in you seeing 1. Also if you are planning to store a variable cross-runs, use `SharedObject` storage, since even a global or static class-wide variable won't preserve its value if you restart your compiled SWF.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers are correct.  Here is a way that might work, similar to what you are doing.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public var a:int = 0;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Main() {
            a = a + 1;
            trace(a);
            Main();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:  This is not good!  it will continue forever and no good will come of it.  This may make more sense :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Main() {
            var a:int = 0;
            while (a < 1000)  // desired upper value here 
            { 
                trace(a); 
                a++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you mean constantly? Also your variable doesn't have initial value:

```
var a:int = 0;
a = a + 1;
trace(a);
```

Comment: A variable of a simple type is assigned initial value when there's no initialization code. For ints, it's 0, but for `Number` type it's `undefined`, which leads to severe butthurt of many a gamedev to date :)

Comment: If somebody keeps getting thrown by uninitialized variables, then something is not being done right.